# Allegro 5 and Visual Studio Express 2013: MSVCR110D.dll missing

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2013, allegro5

I am making a program using Allegro 5. I have got two computers: one with VS Express 2013 for Desktop (I will call it C1) and another one with VS Professional 2013(I will call it C2). On C2, my program works perfectly well but on C1, when I run the program, it says `"Unable to start the program because MSVCR110D.dll is missing on your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem"`
(It's a translation). I have already reinstalled VS and it's still not working (all the linking is correct). Thank you for your viewing and your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you do not have the Visual Studio 2012 runtime installed. MSVCR110D.dll stands for "Microsoft Visual C++ RunTime version 11.0 Debug". Visual Studio 2013 is version 12.0 of Visual Studio, and Visual Studio 2012 is version 11.0.

The Allegro binaries that you have installed were built for Visual Studio 2012, but you're using Visual Studio 2013. Allegro is specifically referencing the Visual Studio 2012 versions of those functions, *not* the VS2013 versions. Unless you have a copy of the library with the Visual Studio 2012 functions, you're stuck.

You can get an installer for the Visual Studio 2012 libraries [from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)--that link will at least get it working in Release mode. Note that there are two downloads. One is for x86, the other is for x64. If you want to get it working in both modes, you need both redistributables.

Unfortunately, there is no legitimate online way to get the debug version of these libraries; your application will only work in Release mode with this solution. However, if you have a copy of Visual Studio 2012 installed somewhere, then you can steal its copy of msvcr110d.dll. There are some *illegitimate* ways of downloading these files directly, but I don't know how safe they are.

Answer (score 0):

go and download MSVCR110D.dll and place it were you put the allegro 5/bin content at. then it should work, i have gotten this error before and this is the only way i know how to fix this.