# How to install allegro 5 on Microsoft visual studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, allegro5

How do I install Allegro 5 in Visual Studio 2013 ?
All I can find is how to install it on the older version of visual studio like 2010,2012.I want to know exactly the proper method to do this.

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21283231/allegro-5-and-visual-studio-express-2013-msvcr110d-dll-missing

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I was looking for to be honest I've already read that one.What I looking for is like where to put allegro 5 in like lib file of vs because now I have on zip file of allegro 5 which I got from there website.

Comment: Now you have to read the installation documentation on the website :)

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all download Allegro5 from: http://cdn.allegro.cc/file/library/allegro/5.0.7/allegro-5.0.7-msvc-10.0.zip
2. then extract the files from the downloaded Archive.
3. copy the folders "bin","lib" and "include" to c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\
4. now create/open a project and in the menu bar, click on "Project", click on " ** Properties" in the drop down menu.
5. Now navigate to "Linker->Input", now in the "Additional Dependencies field enter "allegro-5.0.07-monolith-md-debug.lib". and save the settings.

and you are done. just remember to include Allegro header files therein.