# Allegro - Missing MSVCR110D.dll

Tags: allegro5

I have problems installing Allegro 5. Yesterday I installed Allegro and it worked fine. But then I decided to reinstall it because of a function I tried to call didn't work. Now instead I can't even run the programs. Instead it says that I'm missing MSVCR110D.dll. I've searched around a bit and have gotten somewhat of an insight to what the problem actually is but havn't found any solution that has worked. Is there anyone here who knows how to fix this?

Comment: isn't that the debug version of the run-time? did you call to build your code using release mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allegro 5 and Visual Studio Express 2013: MSVCR110D.dll missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21283231/allegro-5-and-visual-studio-express-2013-msvcr110d-dll-missing)

Comment: From where you got the binaries? What specific version of allegro you downloaded? (5.0/5.1/5.2). What Visual Studio version you have installed? Missing MSVCRxxxD files usually mean you have the wrong version of Allegro or Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Microsoft Visual C++ 2010/2012/2015 missing. Install those version and you will be fine. That works for me.